# How to append multiple values to a key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I'm having trouble being able to asign multiple values to one key within a dictionary. So far I've tried a few methods and the closest one I got to working was this one.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from io import StringIO
f = open('ClassA.txt', 'r')
dictionary = {}
for line in f:
    firstpart, secondpart = line.strip().split(':')
    dictionary[firstpart.strip()] = secondpart.strip()
f.close()
sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(dictionary.items()))
print(sorted_dict)
for key, data in dictionary:
# If this is a new key, create a list to store
# the values
    if not key in mydict:
        dictionary[key] = []
```

Basically ClassA.txt file contains people's name and their score for example:

```
Dan Scored: 10
Jake Scored: 9 
Harry Scored: 5
Berlin Scored: 7
```

And I'm using the ordereddic in order to sort the keys (names) in a alphabetical order.

And the problem I'm trying to resolve is trying to have the same user aka same name or key be able to store multipile scores so when he does the quiz again his scores will be next to his name (key).

So I'm trying to achieve this when i print the dictionary:

```
OrderedDict([('Berlin Scored', '10', '7', '4'), ('Dan Scored', '10'), ('Harry Scored', '5'), ('Jake Scored', '9')
```

Preferably printing the multiple scores from highest to lowest as that will be my next task so I would appreciate any help :)

The problem I encountered with my way of doing it was:

```
for key, data in dictionary:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: I would use a defaultdict, and sort the values instead of an ordereddict

Comment: use a defaultdict, it is very easy sort  any dict for output.

Answer (score 1):

Here when you build the dictionary you are overriding the value for each key:

```
for line in f:
    firstpart, secondpart = line.strip().split(':')
    dictionary[firstpart.strip()] = secondpart.strip()
```

You need to have some sort of check, like:

```
    key = firstpart.strip()
    val = dictionary.get(key,[])
    val.append(secondpart.strip())
    dictionary[key] = val
```

Comment: Where could I implement this within my code ? Like my name states I'm starting out fresh in this whole world of new possibilities.

Comment: Literally replace the first for loop like I showed you.

Comment: Getting an attribute error ;/                                                                                  val = dictionary.get(key,[]).append(secondpart.strip())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: You can do this in one line with `dictionary.setdefault(firstpart.strip(), []).append(secondpart.strip())`

Comment: @augurar Yes its possible, but I figured I use a more simple version for "New Python User"

Comment: @augurar I tried it by putting it in here and getting an error.  `dictionary = {}
    for line in f:
        firstpart, secondpart = line.strip().split(':')    
        dictionary.setdefault(firstpart.strip(), []).append(secondpart.strip())
    f.close()`

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr When i tried your method I encountered another error where the `firstpart` wasn't defined. Idk if its whether I'm actually that bad or simply unable to replace the correct part of the code.

Comment: Dude, I'm not going to debug your code for you. I've shown you how to replace this line: `dictionary[firstpart.strip()] = secondpart.strip()`